# How can I make this block of Android code reusable?

Tags: android, android-activity, dry

I need to show a busy indicator in a number of different activities while data is being loaded.  It's not a difficult problem, but I hate repeating myself.  A base class isn't an option because I don't always extend the same base activity.

```
protected void updateProgressDialog() {
    //we're going to keep the progress dialog around if anything's busy
    if (getBusy()) {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.ProgressDialog);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        }
    } else {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it public static, pass in mProgressDialog, getBusy, and activity context (for "this")

Comment: Put it in any class and make public modifiers and just pass Activity context to it. Or put in any Activity and use that activity as base activity for other activity.

Comment: just pass the context in method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above given answers are pretty clear and correct.
But in case if you do not want to extend all your classes to BaseActivity then you can select other approach. Here it is :-

1. Create one class(Say MyApplication) which would be Subclass of class **Application.**
2. Now register this class in manifest, to do this you just need to give name property(android:name=".MyApplication") to application tag which is already there.
3. Write code for display and dismiss of ProgressDialog in MyApplication class.
4. That's it use it from any activity of your app.

Here is code snippest.

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

void showDialog(String title, String message) {

    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
    }

    progressDialog.setTitle(title);
    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.show();
}

void dismissDialog() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Manifest File (We just applied name property.)

```
 <application android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
```

MainActivity (Activity where we will use showDialog and dismissDialog.)

```
...
((MyApplication) getApplication()).showDialog("Hi", "This is message.");
((MyApplication) getApplication()).dismissDialog();
...
```

Here you don't need to edit your Activities Signature. You just create SubClass of Application class that's it.

Hope this helps !

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any dangers with accessing your application from your activity?  Regardless I think this may be close to my best bet...  I use EventBus so I could easily dispatch busy events from my activities and manage them in my Application.

Comment: Are there any dangers with accessing your application from your activity? - No,

This is called when process of application is created.

This class is used to manage single instance variables across your application generally. So this should not create any issue in your case. 

Here is the link to read more about this class :- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Zealous - No need to pass  `context` in showDialog() method, as you can replace line with `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());` as MyApplication class is already an Application class so it has its own Application Context.

Comment: @user370305 Correct +1. Thanks for pointing out that basic, its updated.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, make a **BaseActivity** put `updateProgressDialog()` method in it. Now, **extends your Activity with this BaseActivity**.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
     ...
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog ;

    protected void updateProgressDialog() {
        //we're going to keep the progress dialog around if anything's busy
        if (getBusy()) {
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.ProgressDialog);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
            }
        } else {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    }
 ...
}
```

Now your other Activity like,

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
     ...
  getBusy()
  {
    .. getBusy() work done
  }
 ...
}
```

Because I assumed `getBusy()` methods are available in in your normal activity.

**Second**, Put it in any Java class and make `updateProgressDialog(Context context, boolean flag)` with activity context and boolean paamters

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog ;

    public void updateProgressDialog(Context context, boolean flag) {
        //we're going to keep the progress dialog around if anything's busy
        if (flag) {
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialog); 
                mProgressDialog.show();
                mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
            }
        } else {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now from your activity call it like,

```
<Class_Object>.updateProgressDialog(this, getBusy()); //Here this refers to Activity reference
```

**Third**, It same as Second but instead of Normal Java Class you have to put your method in **Android Application Class** which has Context own it. So no need to pass Context, only second boolean Argument, Thats it.

And call it like, (From your activity)
 `((<Your_Application_Class>)getApplicationContext()).updateProgressDialog(getBusy());`

Comment: I want to avoid a base activity, because I extend a number of different activities.  I'd still have to duplicate this code by making a BaseFragmentActivity, BaseListActivity, etc.

Comment: @Dennis Try my answer below for the lazy peasant way.

Answer (score 0):

In public static class

```
public static void updateProgressDialog(Context context, ProgressDialog mProgressDialog) {
//If you can't access getBusy(), you may want to use a boolean argument here
if (getBusy()) {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialog); //you might have to cast context, not sure
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
    }
} else {
    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }
}
}
```

The other answer is better practice tho.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a design problem of your app: long time  processes should run in background thread instead if main thread.
Activity's methods called in main (in other name UI) thread and it hangs up the UI if you make a long time process.

If you want to notify the user about the long time background task status you can use:

- AsyncTask onProcessUpdate and onPostExecute method to send notification to MainThread and show the processDialog
- Use some kind of event bus to send notification messages from background thread to ui thread

Asynctask example:

```
public interface UserNotificationService {
    void showProgressBar();
    void hideProgressBar();
}

public class UserNotificationServiceImpl implements UserNotificationService {

    private Context ctx;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;        

    public UserNotificationServiceImpl(Context ctx) { 
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgressBar() {
        if(mProgressDialog == null) {
           mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx, R.style.ProgressDialog);
           mProgressDialog.show();
           mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgressBar() {
        if(mProgressDialog!=null) {
           mProgressDialog.dismiss();
           mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

}
```

background task:

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>     {

   private UserNotificationService notificationService;

   public ExampleTask(Context ctx) {
      notificationService = new UserNotificationServiceImpl(ctx);
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) { 
      // ... do your long time work here ... 
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute () {
      notificationService.showProgressBar();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      notificationService.hideProgressBar();
   }

}
```

Comment: The long processing is definitely happening in background threads.  I'm usually doing it in IntentService.  But in my activity, I need to show the user that we're waiting for a background thread.